# Why when I try serialize current view model WPF app in order to save state later it should be desterilized back I get StackOverflowException?

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, mvvm

```
private async void SynthCodeExecute(object param)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Desktop\report\Config123.cfg", FileMode.Create))
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
                using (var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter))
                {
                    JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
                    ser.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented; //Format the output
                    ser.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto;
                    ser.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                    ser.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                    ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, this); //Serailizing View Model objects
                    jsonWriter.Flush();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I try serialize ''this'' as a json what I do incorrect ?
I try serialize current view model WPF app in order to save state, when I pass for example this.ProprtyName it works, but I need to serialize all data in my view model, so what can I do?

Comment: This is not enough context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show a bit more from your class, to figure out what is going on.

It could be that you have a parent property, which again has the object to serialize as property. This would lead to an endless loop => StackOverflowException

Comment: it is so large model, but thanks.